# android onListItemClick not working when spinners populated within listrow

Tags: android, spinner

I am trying to populate a listview in which the rows contain a checkbox, four textviews, and two spinners. The values in the spinners on each row need to be different as they directly relate to the actual item on that row. Just to make it that little bit more complicated the spinners and the two text fields beside them are not visible (setVisibility(View.GONE)) unless the checkbox is checked. I just want the list item click-able (not the checkbox), and the spinners need to be click-able once they are shown.

All of my code is working correctly except that when the spinners are populated then I lose the ability to click the list item on that row. I can still choose values from the spinners on that row but touching anywhere else on the row does nothing at all. There are some rows that don't return data to the spinners and they continue to operate correctly so I believe it is something to do with the adaptors connected to the spinners.

Also I know I will have to account for the list view recycling but I haven't got that far yet.

I hope someone can point out what is wrong here before I go completely insane.

Here is the listview xml

```
    <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/empty"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the row xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <CheckBox android:id="@+id/pl_selected"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/name2" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/pl_tv1" 
            android:text="@string/pl_tv1" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    <Spinner android:id="@+id/pl_spin1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:focusable="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/pl_tv2"
            android:text="@string/pl_tv2" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

    <Spinner android:id="@+id/pl_spin2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:focusable="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the activity with most of the irrelevant stuff taken out:

```
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import mdhsoft.band.Tab.DbAdapter;
import mdhsoft.band.Tab.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class PLActivity extends ListActivity {
    private static final int DONE_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    private DbAdapter mDbHelper;
private int mPlId;
private CheckBox mCheckBox;
private Spinner mSpin1;
private Spinner mSpin2;
private TextView mtv1;
private TextView mtv2;
private int mItemId; 
private SimpleCursorAdapter mAllItems;
private Cursor mSCursor;
private Cursor mcurSpin1;
private Cursor mcurSpin2;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.pl_list);

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        mPlId = extras.getInt(DbAdapter.KEY_PLID);
        mDbHelper = new DbAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();

        fillData();
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
    }

private void fillData() {
    mSCursor = mDbHelper.fetchAllPl(mPlId);
    startManagingCursor(mSCursor);
    String[] from = new String[]
        {"pl_selected", DbAdapter.KEY_SNAME, DbAdapter.KEY_SNAME2};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.pl_selected, R.id.name, R.id.name2};
    mAllItems = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.pl_row, mSCursor, from, to);
    mAllItems.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {
            if(columnIndex == 3) {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view; 
                    cb.setChecked(cursor.getInt(3) > 0);
                    ViewGroup row = (ViewGroup)view.getParent();
                    if (cursor.getInt(3) > 0) {
                        mcurSpin1 = (Spinner) row.findViewById(R.id.pl_spin1);
                        mcurSpin2 = (Spinner) row.findViewById(R.id.pl_spin2);
                        mtv1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.pl_tv1);
                        mtv2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.pl_tv2);
                        mcurSpin1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mtv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mcurSpin2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mtv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        PopulateSpinner1();
                        PopulateSpinner2(); 
                    }
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    setListAdapter(mAllItems);
}

private void PopulateSpinner1(){
    mcurSpin1 = mDbHelper.fetchSByItemId(mItemId);
    startManagingCursor(mcurSpin1);
    String[] from = new String[]{DbAdapter.KEY_SNAME};
    int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,                  
           android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mcurSpin1, from, to );
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mSpin1.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private void PopulateSpinner2(){
    mcurSpin2 = mDbHelper.fetchMByItemId(mItemId);
    startManagingCursor(mcurSpin2);
    String[] from = new String[]{DbAdapter.KEY_MNAME};
    int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
          android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, mcurSpin2, from, to );
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    mSpin2.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    ViewGroup row = (ViewGroup)v;
    mSCursor.moveToPosition(position);
    mItemId = mSCursor.getInt(mSCursor.getColumnIndex(DbAdapter.KEY_SID));
    mCheckBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.pl_selected);
    mcurSpin1 = (Spinner) row.findViewById(R.id.pl_spin1);
mcurSpin2 = (Spinner) row.findViewById(R.id.pl_spin1);
mtv1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.pl_tv1);
mtv2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.pl_tv2);
    if (mCheckBox.isChecked()) {
        mCheckBox.setChecked(false);
        mcurSpin1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mtv1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mcurSpin2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mtv2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
    else {
        mCheckBox.setChecked(true);
        mcurSpin1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mtv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mcurSpin2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        PopulateSpinner1();
        PopulateSpinner2(); 

    }
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: Try setting the spinners so they cannot get focus.  In the xml `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` and `android:focusable="false"`.  That way they can't steal focus from the list but you can still "click" on them to open up.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already have the touch focus and focus set to false on the spinners. If I take that away the rows where nothing is populated in the spinners breaks so it is needed for sure but doesn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try adding `android:descendantFocussability=blocksDescendants` to the top most linear layout. This might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks Andro, syntax was not quite correct but it solved the issue:

Comment: correct syntax is: android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants". Thanks again.

Comment: Awesome, this really helped! :)