# Onitemclick listener not triggered in Listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a listview, and I am using OnItemClickListener for that listview. At the same time, in getview method of my custom adapter I am using onclicklistener for the entire row view.And I figured out that when using Onclicklisnter in custom adapter, my OnItemClickListener of listview is not triggered. I want to use both these listeners at the same time. Can anyone help me to do it? Thanks in advance.

My listview listener,

```
list_specialists.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                HashMap<String, String> trends_data= new HashMap<String, String>();
                trends_data = specobj.get(position);
                specialist.setText(trends_data.get(KEY_SPEC_TITLE));

                new GetTime(BookingActivity.this).execute();


                }
            });
```

And my getview method inside custom adapter,

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (rowView == null) {
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_timeslot, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.layout = (RelativeLayout) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);
        holder.check = (org.holoeverywhere.widget.CheckBox) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

        rowView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }

    HashMap<String, String> trends_data = new HashMap<String, String>();
    trends_data = trendsobj.get(position);

    holder.check.setId(position);

    holder.check.setChecked(checkarry[position]);

    // for managing the state of the boolean
    // array according to the state of the
    // CheckBox

    holder.check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            for (int i = 0; i < checkarry.length; i++) {
                if (position == i) {
                    checkarry[i] = true;
                } else {
                    checkarry[i] = false;
                }

                RefreshList();
            }
        }
    });

    holder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // Here I am using onclicklistener for rows's parent layout.

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub




            for (int i = 0; i < checkarry.length; i++) {
                if (position == i) {
                    checkarry[i] = true;
                } else {
                    checkarry[i] = false;
                }

                RefreshList();
            }



        }
    });

    holder.title.setText(trends_data.get(BookingActivity.KEY_TIME_TITLE));



    return rowView;
}
```

rowlayout xml file...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/activity_googlecards_card_imageview"
        android:text="Rate "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#757572" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="AED 200.00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/mainservice" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/activity_googlecards_card_imageview"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/activity_googlecards_card_imageview"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Specialist Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#6945B2"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/activity_googlecards_card_imageview"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/activity_googlecards_card_imageview"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/list_dummy" />

</RelativeLayout>*
```

Comment: have you set all your ListRow views to `android:Focusable = fale`..??

Comment: As far as i know, that is not possible.

Comment: @SilentKiller not working..

Comment: DO I need to add other layout above parent, and set onclick listener for that layout?

Comment: @BasimSherif Biradar you dont need to set relative (parent) layout focusable false. make children focusable false.

Comment: Give this solution a try, http://stackoverflow.com/a/10695688/603744

Answer (score 0):

If there is any clickalbe item in the list row, whose click() action will be taking place instead of onItemClickListener. Here you have a checkbox in the row item, and if you still want to use the onItemClickListener, you must make the CheckBox not focusable in the layout as follows:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: @Basim Sherif, Remove the focusable:false of RelativeLayout